# Register bower package with GitHub release attachments

Tags: github, bower, bower-register

As far as I understand [Bower](http://bower.io/) you have to provide a pre-build
 distribution of your package:

> Bower works by fetching and installing packages from all over, taking care of hunting, finding, downloading, and saving the stuff you’re looking for.

But in many projects such pre-build files are not part of the GitHub repository (for very good reasons). Regarding to this [post](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) your are able to attach archives to an release/tag of an GitHub repository. So the best way to register such projects as a Bower package seems to be to use these attachments; instead of a separate repository like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021945/solutions-for-installing-libraries-without-a-prebuilt-file-in-bower). But it [seems](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec/issues/28) this is currently not possible. Am I right?

Comment: From my experience, it seems that the common practice is to just keep the built project in a 'dist'  folder at the root of your repository. I know it's not ideal but that appears to be the most common practice.

Comment: @apatrick In many cases it's less than ideal it's just a horrible idea ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bower currently looks for tarballs associated with git tags on github. Logic is here:
https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/lib/core/resolvers/GitHubResolver.js

@apatrick is correct, currently best practice is to either have a `/dist` folder or have a separate shim repo like this: https://github.com/angular/bower-angular

Using github releases isn't such a bad idea in my opinion. It's been discussed before. Reason for not implementing is here: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/584#issuecomment-20456122

If you feel strongly about it, please ask the contributors to repon the ticket.

Comment: Very good answer! But a sad fact ;). So I think the only possibility to support that Bower crap is a shim repository. Thanks!